# Webpack 4 bundle optimisation, code splitting - React/Redux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, webpack, webpack-4

I'm trying to reduce the size of my bundle.js. Here is my webpack config for production:

```
module.exports = () => {
  return {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/app.js'],
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'dist'),
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      chunkFilename: '[name].js'
    },
    optimization: {
      runtimeChunk: true,
      splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      minSize: 50000,
      maxSize: 250000,
      cacheGroups: {
        vendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: "vendors",
          priority: -10
        },
      }
    },
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJSPlugin({
        uglifyOptions: {
          parse: {
            ecma: 8,
          },
          compress: {
            ecma: 5,
            warnings: false,
            comparisons: false,
          },
          mangle: {
            safari10: true,
          },
          output: {
            ecma: 5,
            comments: false,
            ascii_only: true,
          },
        },
        cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        sourceMap: true
      }),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ]
    },
    module: {
      rules: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },{
        test: /\.css$/,
          use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
      }]
    }, 
    plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({/*env variables*/}),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'styles.css',
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: 'index.ejs', filename: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html')}),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)
  ],
    devtool: 'source-map'
  };
};
```

My app is structured like a classic React/Redux app followed:

```js
|-src
|-|-app.js
|-|-actions
|-|-components
|-|-helpers
|-|-routers
|-|-selectors
|-|-store
```

With this webpack config, I managed to extract the css out and split into chunks of maximum 250kb. I also reduced the size of moment. 
After all this effort, my entrypoint is still a total of 583Kb.

[image: Webpack screenshot]

What else I can do?
I tried lazy loading part of the application but it didn't work. So if you have example of lazy loading for a React app, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I have webpack 6.0.1. Based on the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/) I use the following plugins:

1. webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin() - concatenate the scope
   of all your modules into one closure and allow for your code to have
   a faster execution time in the browser
2. webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin() - cause hashes to be based on the
   relative path of the module, generating a four character string as
   the module id
3. webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin() - vary the
   distribution of the ids to get the smallest id length for often used
   ids
4. webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin() - skip the emitting phase
   whenever there are errors while compiling. This ensures that no
   assets are emitted that include errors

I tested, use the following configuration ideas for webpack.config.js. You can test your configuration against these settings:

```
//webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  ...
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  ...
  plugins : [
    ...
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production') }),
    new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
    new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin({
      hashFunction: 'sha256',
      hashDigest: 'hex',
      hashDigestLength: 4
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
  ],

  ...

  optimization: {
    namedModules: false,
    namedChunks: false,
    nodeEnv: 'production',
    flagIncludedChunks: true,
    occurrenceOrder: true,
    sideEffects: true,
    usedExports: true,
    concatenateModules: true,
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            name: 'vendor',
            chunks: 'all'
        }
      },
      minSize: 30000,
      maxAsyncRequests: 5,
      maxAsyncRequests: 3,      
    },
    noEmitOnErrors: true,
    minimize: true, 
    minimizer: [
      // we specify a custom UglifyJsPlugin here to get source maps in production
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        uglifyOptions: {
          compress: false,
          ecma: 6,
          mangle: true
        },
        sourceMap: true
      })
    ],
    removeAvailableModules: true,
    removeEmptyChunks: true,
    mergeDuplicateChunks: true,    
  },
...
}
```